# React Native [TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined]?

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native

I'm getting this error when I put my Javascipt code to a Typescript project.
In Javascript project its worked fine but when I put the code into a Typescript project I got the error.

Is there any mistake in coding?

Here's the code :

```
const createPDF = async() => {
    let Options = {
      html: '<h1>test</h1>',
      fileName: 'test',
      directory: 'Download',
    };

    let file = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert(Options)
    Alert.alert('Alert','Successfully exported file:' + file.filePath,[
      {text:'Cancel',style:'cancel'},
      {text:'Open',onPress:()=>openFile(file.filepath)}
    ],{cancelable:true});
  }

  const openFile = (filepath: any) => {
    const path = filepath;
    FileViewer.open(path)
    .then(()=>{
      //success
      console.log(`Successfully export PDF file`);
      
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

```
LOG      [TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined]
```

Comment: where is `startsWith` in your code?

Comment: there is no ```startsWith``` in my code

Comment: share full code

Comment: the code worked fine until the alert of 'successfully exported file' shown up and I choose 'Open' then nothing happened and the console show that error log

Comment: here is full of the javascript code : https://github.com/vishalpwr/react-native/blob/master/CreatePdf/ExportPdf.js

Comment: I put the code into my Typecsript project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I have solved the problem by adding `string` type and `:void` to **filepath** instead of `any`  ( i dont know what this mean but it worked )

```
  const openFile = (filepath: string):void => {
    const path = filepath;
    FileViewer.open(path, { showOpenWithDialog: true })
    .then(()=>{
      //success
      console.log(`Successfully export PDF file`);
      
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```